# Django query not outputting correct result

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model named `Post` and another model named `Share` A user can create Posts or share Posts. I'm using the following query:

```
Post.objects.filter(
            Q(user=user) |
            Q(share__user=user)
        ).annotate(
            shared_or_created=Coalesce('share__shared_at', 'created_at')
        ).order_by('-shared_or_created')
```

With this query, I'm getting the correct posts, however, let's say another user (user B) shared this user's post then the `shared_at` field will be the time that user B shared it. So if the user has 3 posts and 1 user shared that user's post, then two of the posts will have the correct time when the post was created and the third post will have the time when User B shared that post.

The logic should be to show the user's posts and the posts shared by them in descending order. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [conditional annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#django.db.models.expressions.Case) to annotate a value based on a condition

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Case, When, F

Post.objects.filter(
    Q(user=user) |
    Q(share__user=user)
).annotate(
    shared_or_created=Case(
        When(user=user, then=F('created_at')),
        When(share__user=user, then=F('share__shared_at')),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    )
).order_by('-shared_or_created')
```